# Mouse Event for another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have some code in one class

MainPage

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    //unsure what goes here
    textField_tf1.setText(char);
}
```

In another class (NumberGen) I have a random number generator that when you run it will give you a number between 1-10. How would I get that class to run, create the number and then take it and put it in the text field just by clicking a the button on the MainPage.

Comment: Can you provide the NumberGen class?

Comment: All I have at the moment is Random rand = new Random();

int  char = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your NumberGen class looks something like this:

```
public class NumberGen {

    public int getRandom() {
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        return rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
    }
}
```

You'd use it in your MainPage class like this:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // Create an instance of your NumberGen class
    NumberGen numberGenerator = new NumberGen();
    // Set the text field to the random number
    textField_tf1.setText(numberGenerator.getRandom());
}
```

Comment: This works, but I'm trying to keep the generator in a separate class. Or is this a bad move?

Comment: I've edited it to make it clear, does it make sense now?